# Flutter lower dart version

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart

I'm getting the following error due to Dart version of my flutter setup when I run the `flutter get packages` command:

> [project_name] flutter packages get   Running "flutter packages get"
>   in project_name...
>   The current Dart SDK version is
>   2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f.
>
> Because project depends on intl_translation >=0.14.0+1 <0.17.0 which
>   requires SDK version >=1.12.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed. pub get
>   failed (1) exit code 1

My framework version:

> Flutter 0.6.0 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
>   Framework • revision 9299c02cf7 (2 weeks ago) • 2018-08-16 00:35:12 +0200
>   Engine • revision e3687f70c7
>   Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f

I would like to learn if there's some kind of command to lower dart-sdk version of the flutter framework, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you limit `intl_translations` to `<0.17.0`? `intl_translations: ^0.17.0` works for me.

Comment: `intl_translation: "^0.16.7"` with `intl: ^0.15.4` in implementation, so I didn't want to change it

Comment: Then you can't switch to a Flutter version that includes Dart 2.

Comment: Actually, the problem seems version of Dart 2.1.0, I only need Dart 2.0.0

Comment: It's unlikely 2.1.0, but instead 2.0.0 that causes the problem. If a dependency has `2.0.0-...` this is lower than `2.0.0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Flutter install directory execute

```
git checkout v"0.5.0" // for example
```

You can check which versions are available in the Flutter GitHub repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter

Comment: git checkout v"1.9.1+hotfix.6" 
Don't work:
error: pathspec 'v1.9.1+hotfix.6' did not match any file(s) known to git

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the Dart version if you change to a Flutter version that contains the desired Dart version.

Change the dependency to

```
dev_dependencies:
  intl_translations: ^0.17.0
```

Comment: besides changing the dependency, how is it possible to change flutter version?

Comment: You can checkout a specific branch using `flutter channel` or a specific tag using `git checkout [branch, tag or commit hash]`. Then run `flutter doctor`

Comment: so the dart sdk is basically bundled within flutter sdk there's no way to configure versions separately

Comment: Exactly, there is no way.

Comment: so basically, I have changed the dependency to `intl_translation: 0.17.0` and it's working with the latest flutter/dart-sdk version

Comment: Sounds great. .

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency in **pubspec.yaml** file

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: can you be more specific on what it really does?