# How to run flutter projects with different/older Dart SDK dependencies?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.

Because NewsBuzz requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
```

I am trying to run projects from https://startflutter.com. There are several older projects using older versions of Dart SDK or with dependencies requiring older Dart SDK version.

Is there any way to run multiple versions of Dart without downloading the older version of Dart and changing the environment variables manually?

I have gone through several StackOverflow posts and lot of Github issues without finding a proper solution.

1. [Flutter lower dart version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102360/flutter-lower-dart-version)
2. [Where is Dart's SDK located within /flutter folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321966/where-is-darts-sdk-located-within-flutter-folder)

Specifying SDK version in the `pubspec.yaml` does not seem to help.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
```

Edit: [Dart & Flutter support for Visual Studio Code](https://dartcode.org/docs/quickly-switching-between-sdk-versions/) docs says something about `dart.sdkPaths` and `dart.flutterSdkPaths` settings.

Comment: Clone and update `NewsBuzz` to work with current Dart/Flutter versions. Ideally make a Pull Request afterwards to the original package.

Comment: I don't wish to update every flutter app I come across. I was hoping to run it isolated without having to upgrade/downgrade my flutter installation. Like we do with angular/ionic apps or NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem:

My pubspec.yaml had the following:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

However when running `flutter packages get` I got the following error:

```
Running "flutter packages get" in xxx-app-mobile...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.

Because xxx_app requires SDK version >=2.1.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
```

I tried using the exact version name as the environment variable it did not work. I tried:

```
flutter upgrade
flutter clean
flutter update-packages
```

Received the same error when running `flutter packages get` 
I then downgraded the version requirements in the pubspec.yaml to:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0 <3.0.0"
```

And `flutter packages get` worked...

Answer (score 0):

So I had an app that was developed on flutter 1.x SDK's, but after my completion, I moved on to build other projects and eventually shifted to fllutter2.0

As of now, flutter downgrade only lets you go one version back, Also going back from 2.x to 1.x seems difficult

So I went to this `https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases` site and downloaded the version i made the app in.
Then I had my dart-sdk for that specific project changed in Android Studio
Then I did the following

**Deleted .idea folder and build folder as well as pubspec-lock file.
run flutter pub get
finally flutter build apk**

Now this was a dire situation so I had to resort to this
I really will not recommend this unless you are in a rough spot

Answer (score -1):

Simply update you flutter sdk to latest version.

Answer (score -2):

First open your command (cmd) as an adminstrator then upgrade flutter : **flutter upgrade** it will do everything for you

Comment: Unless you work on pet project, you can't just upgrade in production app.